# Java Home Directory

Tags: java, java-home

I am looking for my java home directory. When I tried "whereis java" I got `java: /usr/share/java` but then when I did `ls -lah /usr/share/java` I got:

```
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Aug 13 04:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 100 root root 4.0K Aug 13 04:38 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.6K Apr 28 15:43 libintl.jar
```

Could someone please clue me in?

Comment: did you try `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Which OS are you using and version?

Comment: @raffian I tried echo $JAVA_HOME and it came up blank, so I guess it's not set yet.
I am using ubuntu version 14.04

Comment: ...and you're *sure* that you've got Java installed?  (`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`)

Comment: try the command `which java`. It will try to locate the command `java` in your PATH. The folder `/usr/share/java` is a jar repository, but seems strangely empty. If you want to check if you have your java installed, try this: `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep openjdk`

Comment: If your Java is installed from packages, it will be in a few different folders. The main part is probably in `/usr/lib/jvm/YOUR_JDK` and config files will be under `/etc/YOUR_JDK`.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: I tried `which java` and it nothing came up. I think maybe it hasn't been installed yet. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I have installed java now, and I found the path to be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.3.fc20.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java` but when I try to check the hadoop version I get `./hadoop: line 133: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.3.fc20.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory`

Answer (score 1):

The SDK's are located at:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm
default-java  java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

To set JAVA_HOME just point it at default-java (which is just a symlink for selected java version)

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```